# Useing str_replace to replace In two strings that contains new added text

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to replace a part of the string, but the function str_replace prints the exact same original string without replacing it! I know this because my first and second string has heaps of double quote marks, and I've tried to solve the problem but I failed!

**My code:**

```
$update_this_item = $test_array[$key].",";
$updated_item = $data_item[0].",".($data_item[1]+1).",".$data_item[2].",".$data_item[3].",".$data_item[4].",".$data_item[5].",";
echo str_replace($update_this_item, $updated_item, $test);
```

**I will explain this strings for you:**

```
$test = "2021/05/11,1024,260,600,180,450|2021/05/10,1024,260,600,180,450|2021/05/09,1024,260,600,180,450|2021/05/08,1024,260,600,180,450|2021/05/07,1024,260,600,180,450";
echo $test_array[$key]; //2021/05/11,1024,260,600,180,450
echo $updated_item; //2021/05/11,1025,260,600,180,450,
```

I hope to find a solution for this issue, Thanks heaps!

Comment: Can you please share a clear `var_export` of all variables involved? Currently I'm not sure if `//` is a comment or part of the output.

Comment: Anyway, you attach a comma at the end of your search value: `$update_this_item = $test_array[$key].",";`, but in your test string a pipe `|` comes after the last value, not a comma.

Comment: @El_Vanja This is the output of the string

Comment: @El_Vanja I've removed the comma from the end of both strings and the problem solved! ‍♂️ Thank you for reminding me of that! you don't know how much time I've spent trying to solve this issue!! Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

in $test you have not ','
than
instead of

```
$update_this_item = $test_array[$key].",";
```

use

```
 $update_this_item = $test_array[$key];
```